Unknown blob when pushing to Artifactory , with s3 as the storage
Pushing images to our artifactory instance, throws the error unknown blob after pushing images
the error logs show
Deploy to 'docker-local:docker-local/mongo/_uploads/6d562ef3-cab2-4b8d-b60e-f4d5b6a05c2d' Content-Length: 0 (estimation) artificial: false

Failed while saving temp file /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/artifactory/filestore/_pre/dbRecord870694586599854700-35d5a484b17b6f0a-docker-local.bin
org.jfrog.storage.binstore.ifc.ClientInputStreamException: Failed to read stream: Failed to read stream: java.io.EOFException
Caused by: org.jfrog.storage.binstore.ifc.ClientInputStreamException: Failed to read stream: java.io.EOFException
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.EOFException
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
2024-09-12T08:20:21.331Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [35d5a484b17b6f0a] [c.e.m.GlobalExceptionMapper:51] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-97] - org.jfrog.storage.StorageException: Failure during saveToTempFileAndUpload
org.artifactory.storage.StorageException: org.jfrog.storage.StorageException: Failure during saveToTempFileAndUpload
        at org.artifactory.sh.service.ArtifactoryBinaryServiceImpl.addBinary(ArtifactoryBinaryServiceImpl.java:140)
        at org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.saveResource(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:2649)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor359.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:234)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy74.saveResource(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadItemWithContent(UploadServiceImpl.java:795)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadItemWithProvidedContent(UploadServiceImpl.java:766)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadItem(UploadServiceImpl.java:629)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadFile(UploadServiceImpl.java:618)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadArtifact(UploadServiceImpl.java:597)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.adjustResponseAndUpload(UploadServiceImpl.java:335)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.validateRequestAndUpload(UploadServiceImpl.java:290)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.processUpload(UploadServiceImpl.java:228)
        at org.artifactory.api.request.GracefulShutdownAware.track(GracefulShutdownAware.java:36)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.upload(UploadServiceImpl.java:210)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor351.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)

Trying to push images with docker client, we expect the image to be pushed to artifactory, but we get the unknown blob error
Binarystore.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<config version="2">
    <chain>
        <provider type="cache-fs" id="cache-fs">
            <provider type="s3-storage-v3" id="s3-storage-v3"/>
        </provider>
    </chain>
    <provider type="cache-fs" id="cache-fs">
        <maxCacheSize>100000000000</maxCacheSize>
        <cacheProviderDir>cache</cacheProviderDir>
    </provider>
    <provider type="s3-storage-v3" id="s3-storage-v3">
        <bucketName>bucket-name</bucketName>
        <enablePathStyleAccess>true</enablePathStyleAccess>
        <testConnection>false</testConnection>
        <signatureExpirySeconds>300</signatureExpirySeconds>
        <signedUrlExpirySeconds>30</signedUrlExpirySeconds>
        <usePresigning>false</usePresigning>
        <useInstanceCredentials>false</useInstanceCredentials>
        <path>filestore</path>
        <endpoint>https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com</endpoint>
        <credential> secret-key</credential>
        <port>443</port>
        <identity></identity>
        <region>eu-west-1</region>
        <connectionTimeout>12000</connectionTimeout>
        <maxConnections>100</maxConnections>
    </provider>
</config>

S3 Debug logs - These are the s3 debug logs when uploading to artifactory
Caused by: org.jfrog.storage.StorageException: Failure during saveToTempFileAndUpload
        at org.jfrog.type.s3.S3AwsBinaryProvider.saveToTempFileAndUpload(S3AwsBinaryProvider.java:284)
        at org.jfrog.type.s3.S3AwsBinaryProvider.addStream(S3AwsBinaryProvider.java:236)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.providers.cachefs.FileCacheBinaryProviderImpl.addStream(FileCacheBinaryProviderImpl.java:225)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.providers.federated.FederatedBinaryProvider.addStream(FederatedBinaryProvider.java:360)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.BinaryServiceImpl.addStreamToBinaryProviderIfNeeded(BinaryServiceImpl.java:1342)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.BinaryServiceImpl.addBinary(BinaryServiceImpl.java:435)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.BinaryServiceImpl.addBinary(BinaryServiceImpl.java:422)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy109.addBinary(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.sh.service.ArtifactoryBinaryServiceImpl.addBinary(ArtifactoryBinaryServiceImpl.java:138)
        ... 115 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.storage.binstore.ifc.ClientInputStreamException: Failed to read stream: Failed to read stream: java.io.EOFException
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.ifc.ClientStream.read(ClientStream.java:36)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1487)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1107)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1460)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1085)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyToFile(FileUtils.java:1026)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(FileUtils.java:934)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.providers.tools.FilePersistenceHelper.saveStreamToTempFile(FilePersistenceHelper.java:52)
        at org.jfrog.type.s3.S3AwsBinaryProvider.saveToTempFileAndUpload(S3AwsBinaryProvider.java:269)
        ... 135 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.jfrog.storage.binstore.ifc.ClientInputStreamException: Failed to read stream: java.io.EOFException
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.ifc.ClientStream.read(ClientStream.java:36)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.common.SavedToFileInputStream.read(SavedToFileInputStream.java:80)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.ifc.ClientStream.read(ClientStream.java:34)
        ... 143 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:312)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.checkByteBufferEof(InputBuffer.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:358)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:132)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream.read(EntityInputStream.java:79)
        at org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream.read(ProxyInputStream.java:205)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:282)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.common.Sha1Sha2Md5ChecksumInputStream.read(Sha1Sha2Md5ChecksumInputStream.java:134)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.common.Sha1Sha2Md5ChecksumInputStream.read(Sha1Sha2Md5ChecksumInputStream.java:118)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.ifc.ClientStream.read(ClientStream.java:34)
        ... 145 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1320)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1231)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:789)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$400(Http11InputBuffer.java:41)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1195)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedInputFilter.readBytes(ChunkedInputFilter.java:254)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedInputFilter.fill(ChunkedInputFilter.java:295)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedInputFilter.parseChunkHeader(ChunkedInputFilter.java:328)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedInputFilter.doRead(ChunkedInputFilter.java:136)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:244)
        at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:626)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:303)
        ... 155 common frames omitted
2024-09-24T08:14:15.987Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [0b267ff79eb8c702] [o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:595   ] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-17] - Deploy to 'docker-local:docker-local/mongo/_uploads/e9f9ea1b-dc3c-4efa-8539-d47f92e1661b' Content-Length: 0 (estimation) artificial: false
2024-09-24T08:14:15.988Z [jfrt ] [DEBUG] [0b267ff79eb8c702] [.j.t.s.S3AwsBinaryProvider:235] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-17] - Uploading to S3 by writing to temp file and upload it
2024-09-24T08:14:15.989Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [0b267ff79eb8c702] [.j.t.s.S3AwsBinaryProvider:283] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-17] - Failed while saving temp file /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/artifactory/filestore/_pre/dbRecord1634185649544764957-0b267ff79eb8c702-docker-local.bin
2024-09-24T08:14:15.989Z [jfrt ] [DEBUG] [0b267ff79eb8c702] [.j.t.s.S3AwsBinaryProvider:283] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-17] -
org.jfrog.storage.binstore.ifc.ClientInputStreamException: Failed to read stream: Failed to read stream: java.io.EOFException
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.ifc.ClientStream.read(ClientStream.java:36)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1487)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1107)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1460)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1085)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyToFile(FileUtils.java:1026)
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(FileUtils.java:934)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.providers.tools.FilePersistenceHelper.saveStreamToTempFile(FilePersistenceHelper.java:52)
        at org.jfrog.type.s3.S3AwsBinaryProvider.saveToTempFileAndUpload(S3AwsBinaryProvider.java:269)
        at org.jfrog.type.s3.S3AwsBinaryProvider.addStream(S3AwsBinaryProvider.java:236)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.providers.cachefs.FileCacheBinaryProviderImpl.addStream(FileCacheBinaryProviderImpl.java:225)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.providers.federated.FederatedBinaryProvider.addStream(FederatedBinaryProvider.java:360)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.BinaryServiceImpl.addStreamToBinaryProviderIfNeeded(BinaryServiceImpl.java:1342)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.BinaryServiceImpl.addBinary(BinaryServiceImpl.java:435)
        at org.jfrog.storage.binstore.BinaryServiceImpl.addBinary(BinaryServiceImpl.java:422)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:241)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy109.addBinary(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.sh.service.ArtifactoryBinaryServiceImpl.addBinary(ArtifactoryBinaryServiceImpl.java:138)
        at org.artifactory.repo.service.RepositoryServiceImpl.saveResource(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:2649)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:234)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy74.saveResource(Unknown Source)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadItemWithContent(UploadServiceImpl.java:795)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadItemWithProvidedContent(UploadServiceImpl.java:766)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadItem(UploadServiceImpl.java:629)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadFile(UploadServiceImpl.java:618)
        at org.artifactory.engine.UploadServiceImpl.uploadArtifact(UploadServiceImpl.java:597)


Irule

when HTTP_REQUEST {
    set uri [string tolower [HTTP::uri]]
    set host_header [string tolower [HTTP::host]]
    set path [string tolower [HTTP::path]]

    SSL::disable serverside 


    if { ($host_header equals "artifactory.subdomain") or 
     ($host_header equals "IP address") } {
        HTTP::header insert "X-Forwarded-Proto" "https";
        HTTP::header insert "X-Forwarded-Port" "443";
        HTTP::header insert "X-Forwarded-For" [IP::remote_addr];
        HTTP::header insert "X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url" "https://artifactory.subdomain";


        if { ($uri starts_with "/v1") or ($uri starts_with "/v2") } {

          set version [substr $uri 1 "/"]
          set docker_path [substr $uri 4]

          HTTP::uri /artifactory/api/docker/docker-virtual/$version/$docker_path

        }

        pool new_artifactory_pool
        return
    }


What Artifactory version are you using? additionally, add the commands you used for pushing

Hi @rahman-the-man. The org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException seems to indicate that something happened while uploading the binary.
What client are you using for uploading? Can you enable logs on it?
Can you also paste the binarystore.xml please?

Hi @ArielKogan, i'm using dockercli and the binary store has been added to the question

Hi @Tom.A , artifactory version 7.90.8 , and the command is docker push registry/image-name

@RahmanTheMan, thanks for the info. Seems that there is something going on with the configuration there. The log you quoted reads:
Failed while saving temp file /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/artifactory/filestore/_pre/dbRecord870694586599854700-35d5a484b17b6f0a-docker-local.bin

Pointing to a configuration where binaries are stored in the filesystem (see /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/artifactory/filestore). But according to your binarystore.xml, the storage is S3.
Did you change the storage at some point? Do other uploads work and you see the binaries in the S3 bucket?

Hi @ArielKogan yes we had to change the storage from our on prem storage to s3 because of the limitations of our new license so we did a sync of all files stored from on prem to s3, but pulling images work and pushing images don’t work. Also uploading with curl commands work, because we use that to push our helm charts

I see. If you are working with S3 now, can you please run the upload and send me the updated log message? May be worth configuring the logger for the package org.jfrog.type.s3 to DEBUG to get more information.

Alright @ArielKogan, will do that

Hi @ArielKogan, i've added the logs to the question

Thanks for the logs @RahmanTheMan.
I think there is something either with the client deploying or the environment. Can you please check the following:

Deploy a file to Artifactory using curl. Please upload a big file, 1GB let's say.
Check the disk space of that machine. I haven't tried it yet but maybe a lack of space can throw that exception. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40992148/how-low-disk-space-can-cause-java-io-eofexception


Hi @ArielKogan , i just uploaded a file of 1.25Gb with curl and it went through, there is also space on the machine

Great @RahmanTheMan, so the system works well. The client is aborting the connection. Some ideas: Try different versions of the client, try enabling debugging logs for the client, check the configuration of the client, maybe it's using a proxy.

how can i enable debug logs for docker client

Hi @ArielKogan, its using a proxy, but the url of our artifactory is in its no proxy config

@RahmanTheMan, seem that the issue is somewhere in the middle, maybe even that proxy. Try hitting Artifactory directly if you can. Your Artifactory seems to be working well from the tests you performed.

@ArielKogan , we use a reverse proxy and an IRule  to forward traffic to artifactory.
The rule is in my question

Hi @ArielKogan, awaiting response

Hi @RahmanTheMan. I think the issue is somewhere in the networking. Can the proxy be set on debug to see what's happening? Same if there is such possibility for the iRule. I'm almost sure that if you manage to hit Artifactory with the Docker client on the same network, it will work well.
